# How to pass "evt" as an argument in Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, events

This is a method to send `evt` as an argument to access latitude and longitude:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,"click", function(evt){//some code about Google maps});
```

This is something I want to do:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", draw_way(evt));
```

I want to call another function when I click on the map and send `evt` as an argument to the specified function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. It was very easy.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,"click", function(){draw_way(evt)});
```